# How to design the models in OptaPlanner in my case

Tags: optaplanner

I have been started to learn Opataplanner for sometime, I try to figure out a model design for my use case to progress the solution calculation, here is my case in real world in manufactory's production line:

1. There is a working order involved list of sequential processes
2. Each kind of machine can handle fixed types of processes.(assume machine quantity are enough)
3. The involved team has a number of available employees, each employee has the skills for set of processes with their different own working cost time
4. production line has fixed number of stations available
5. each station put one machine/employee or leave empty

question: how to design the model to calculate the maximum output of completion product in one day.

confusion: in the case, the single station will have one employee and one machined populated, and specified dynamic processed to be working on. but the input of factors are referred by each other and dynamic:  employee => processes skill , process skill => machines

can please help to guide how to design the models?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of the examples are close to your requirements. [See their docs here.](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/use-cases-and-examples/use-cases-and-examples.html) Specifically the **task assignment**, **cheap time scheduling** or **project job scheduling** examples.

Otherwise, [follow the domain modeling guidelines](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/design-patterns/design-patterns.html#domainModelingGuide).